# Live Video Broadcasting in Android using Wowza Server

Tags: android, android-broadcast, wowza, broadcasting

I have tried **broadcasting** videos in Android app through Wowza server and it works pretty well with [this demo of javaCV.](https://github.com/vanevery/JavaCV_0.3_stream_test)

But the only problem with this is that it uses flv file format to broadcast on Wowza server. It uses **FFmpegFrameRecorder** to broadcast live video to wowza server (not VOD). To set format of the video broadcasted at server, it uses following method:

```
recorder.setFormat("flv");
```

So the main problem with this method is that when I use other formats, it doesn't work. For E.g.:

```
recorder.setFormat("mpeg"); //or something like mov, etc
```

***Please suggest a way to broadcast video from Android device to wowza server with any format other than flv.*** Please provide any links or tutorials with which I can start.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit:*** I am able to play only audio while streaming vlc video format in Android and iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not container, but protocol. For live streaming, your best options are RTMP, RTP/RTSP. RTMP is essentially FLV with VCR style commands (play pause stop). There is no streaming protocol for MP4, except HTTP. and this would require you to produce a new mp4 ever few seconds and reassemble server side.

Im not sure you FLV/RTMP is off limits to you, because it probably is the best. But next I would suggest RTSP, and maybe WebRTC.

Comment: @szatmary- I also need to stream that link in another module of the app. Flv is only gives audio in my android device but not video. Same stream also needs to work in iOS application. Is there any way to stream it in device Android and iOS with FLV format, because that would be just great !

Comment: Thats a different question. The only way to do live video in iOS is HLS.

Comment: As far as no video on android using flv. Is it because of the codec? The only codec supported by both android and flv is AVC.

Comment: Yes, I think its because of Codec only. But I can't find AVC codec in Android's avcodec class from javacv library. Can you suggest any way on how to integrate the AVC codec ?